# Alternating links and slide down content on a list of sub sections

Tags: seo, content

I have a page for a doctor's practice. In the summary page for the practice there is a list of subsections such as Women's, Men's, Children, Sport, etc. Some of these sub sections are very large, others can be a paragraph or more with a short unordered list.

In terms of content volume, the large subsections warrant their own separate page, the smaller one's not so much. I created a little plugin which enables me to use the list of subsections in 2 ways. When clicking on the title of a larger section, you'll be sent through to it's own page. For the smaller sections, a slide down box will open with the information.

Is this a good way to handle my information architecture? Should I be giving the smaller sub sections their own page for SEO purposes?

Answer (score 1):

You should always put your visitors first over the search engines so if the site looks better, feels better and gives an overall better experience with those on the right side in full then you should go with it. If the content is far to much to put on the right side then you should consider to put them on their own page, but both methods are valid.

You want to look into using aside element so your informing that the search engines these are links and the content surrronding them is not diluting the authorithy of your pages.

For example:

```
<article>
    <h1>Surgery Information</h1>
    <p>I am the content about Surgery Information</p>
</article>
<!-- We now close the article to tell Google and co that the article is finished. -->
<!-- We now use a aside element which is not contained within article -->
<!-- This means the content outside article is not completely relevant to the article -->
<aside>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="accord">Mens Health</a>
            <div class="hidden">
                <p>I am hidden content</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Another possibility is that you use an Ajax modal box, so when the users click for examples men health they get a nice tidy modal both which ajax reteives the data from another page, this means for users they are able to view the information without switching page, and the search engines are welcome to rank the full page on a separate URL.